# $ mongosh gives MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm getting `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` when trying to start mongo locally with `$ mongosh`.

```
$ mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 636addb4****************
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Some details: I killed some process at some point to try to stop mongo so I could run `run-rs -v 4.0.0 --shell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I had installed mongo with brew this worked

```
$ brew services stop mongodb-community
$ brew services start mongodb-community
$ mongosh
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark sure mongod is running.You could start it manually if it is in your system environmental variables path by typing mongod in your terminal

```
mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem than after reinstalling the package helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Vivek, while this answer might be helpful in this situation, it might be more fitting to post it as a comment to the question instead of a separate answer, since it is a very short suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had only installed mongosh and not mongodb as well.
Somehow they are separated are require different installations.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issues and fixed with  below steps.

1. Open Run (Window + R)
2. Type services.msc and hit enter
3. In services(Local), search for MongoDB Server (MongoDB), do the right click and just start it.
4. Above these simple steps will fix this problem.